# RavenDb with ASP.NET MVC 3 - How to generate URL with ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

This is probably a very simple answer, but i'm new to RavenDb, so i'm obviously missing something.

I've got a basic object with the default convention for id:

```
public string Id { get; set; }
```

When i save it to the document store, i see it gets a value of like:

> posts/123

Which is fine, but...how do i generate a URL like this:

> www.mysite.com/edit/123

If i do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Posts", new { id = @Model.Id })
```

It will generate the followiung URL:

> www.mysite.com/edit/posts/123

Which is not what i want.

Surely i don't have to do string manipulation? How do people approach this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

RPM1984,
There are several ways you can deal with that.

1) You can modify your routing to handle this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                                // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{*id}",                            // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });  // Parameter defaults
```

This will allow MVC to accept parameters with slashes in them

2) You can modify the default id generation strategy:

```
 documentStore.Conventions.IdentityPartsSeparator = "-";
```

This will generate ids with:

posts-1
posts-2
etc

See also here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/06/04/how-to-work-ravendb-id-with-asp-net-mvc-routes.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ayende - i'll go with option 2. BTW, i missed your Raven webinar last night because it kept saying "Invalid ID, please try again". :( Any plans to post the audio/video for the webinar somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use ...

```
int Id;
```

..instead of ...

```
string Id;
```

in your entity classes :)

Comment: No you cant. Not without changing the Hilo settings.

Comment: elegant simple solution! ;-) I like that!

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to extract the integer value out of the documents string-based id. This is because raven can actually handle any kind of Id, not necessarily a HILO-generated integer (this is default if you do not specify an id by your own).

Take a look at RaccoonBlog sample. There is a helper class "RavenIdResolver" inside which makes it really easy to get the numeric id out of the documents-id.